# Django application on heroku is failing when turning off DEBUG

Tags: django, heroku

Am facing a strange behavior on heroku where I developed an application and its fully running fine, it uses multiple plugins such as social auth, storages, django-ses.

Any ways, the app is running fine as long as the DEBUG mode is turned on, once I turn it off I get an error complaining from an import operation which is very strange

Here is the stack, anyone experienced this before?

```
2013-09-18T13:30:18.929630+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-09-18 08:30:18 [7] [ERROR] Error handling request
2013-09-18T13:30:18.929630+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2013-09-18T13:30:18.929630+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 126, in handle_request
2013-09-18T13:30:18.929630+00:00 app[web.1]:     respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
2013-09-18T13:30:18.929630+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 255, in __call__
2013-09-18T13:30:18.929630+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = self.get_response(request)
2013-09-18T13:30:18.929630+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 178, in get_response
2013-09-18T13:30:18.929630+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
2013-09-18T13:30:18.929630+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 220, in handle_uncaught_exception
2013-09-18T13:30:18.930013+00:00 app[web.1]:     if resolver.urlconf_module is None:
2013-09-18T13:30:18.930013+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 342, in urlconf_module
2013-09-18T13:30:18.930013+00:00 app[web.1]:     self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
2013-09-18T13:30:18.930013+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
2013-09-18T13:30:18.930013+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(name)
2013-09-18T13:30:18.930013+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/khooosh/urls.py", line 8, in <module>
2013-09-18T13:30:18.930013+00:00 app[web.1]:     admin.autodiscover()
2013-09-18T13:30:18.930013+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 29, in autodiscover
2013-09-18T13:30:18.930013+00:00 app[web.1]:     import_module('%s.admin' % app)
2013-09-18T13:30:18.930013+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
2013-09-18T13:30:18.930277+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(name)
2013-09-18T13:30:18.930277+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social_auth/admin.py", line 19, in <module>
2013-09-18T13:30:18.930277+00:00 app[web.1]:     all_names = _User._meta.get_all_field_names()
2013-09-18T13:30:18.930277+00:00 app[web.1]: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

Update settings.py

```
import dj_database_url
import os
import sys


BASE_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),
                                        os.path.pardir, os.path.pardir))


def base(f=''):
    return os.path.join(BASE_DIR, f)


def app_base(f=''):
    return os.path.join(base('XXXX'), f)


sys.path.insert(0, app_base())

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    ('Mo Mughrabi', 'XXXX'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config()}

# Hosts/domain names that are valid for this site; required if DEBUG is False
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*', ]

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# In a Windows environment this must be set to your system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'
ADMIN_LANGUAGE_CODE = LANGUAGE_CODE

gettext = lambda s: s

LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', gettext('English')),
    ('ar', gettext('Arabic'))
)

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale.
USE_L10N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not use timezone-aware datetimes.
USE_TZ = True

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/var/www/example.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = base('public_media')

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://example.com/media/", "http://media.example.com/"
MEDIA_URL = '/public_media/'

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/var/www/example.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = ''

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://example.com/static/", "http://static.example.com/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    app_base('public-assets'),
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    #    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = '+_-$@5jw*k)43blbi%ky!vlvi8dvhlotre&9eui!6&0$qnf0c^'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'apps.rank.middleware.HitCountMiddleware',
    'middleware.LocaleMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'urls'

# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'khooosh.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.debug',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    'django.core.context_processors.tz',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
    # custom context processors
    'khooosh.context_processors.load_settings',
    'constance.context_processors.config',
)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    base('templates'),
)

# custom user model
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'account.User'

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # suit admin
    'suit',
    'suit_redactor',
    'suit_ckeditor',
    'filebrowser',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    # apps
    'south',
    'mptt',
    'storages',
    'constance.backends.database',
    'social_auth',
    'captcha',
    'modeltranslation',
    'tinymce',
    'sorl.thumbnail',
    'djcelery',
    'django_extensions',
    'haystack',
    # apps custom
    'apps.media',
    'apps.account',
    'apps.list',
    'apps.bargain',
    'apps.promotion',
    'apps.pages',
    'apps.dwh',
    'apps.campaigner',
    'apps.rank',
    'apps.mail_list',
    'apps.search'
)


# A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
# performed by this configuration is to send an email to
# the site admins on every HTTP 500 error when DEBUG=False.
# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}

SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

# constance config
CONSTANCE_CONFIG = {}
CONSTANCE_BACKEND = 'constance.backends.database.DatabaseBackend'

# custom settings
TEMPLATE_PUBLIC_ASSETS = 'leisure'

# reCaptcha details
RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY = '6Leu6-QSAAAAAJPxSFBrIVDoSF9u2JF7i6LfX6Sm'
RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY = '6Leu6-QSAAAAAOAWWy9f7CUX5PIbbN0DSbLJmUFg'

# authentication backends
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social_auth.backends.twitter.TwitterBackend',
    'social_auth.backends.facebook.FacebookBackend',
    'social_auth.backends.google.GoogleOAuthBackend',
    'social_auth.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2Backend',
    'social_auth.backends.google.GoogleBackend',
    'social_auth.backends.contrib.linkedin.LinkedinBackend',
    'social_auth.backends.contrib.instagram.InstagramBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'backends.EmailAuthBackend',
)

TWITTER_EXTRA_DATA = [
    ('screen_name', 'screen_name'),
    ('user_info', 'user_info')
]

FACEBOOK_EXTRA_DATA = [
    ('username', 'username'),
    ('gender', 'gender'),
    ('bio', 'bio'),
    ('last_name', 'last_name'),
    ('link', 'link'),
    ('middle_name', 'middle_name'),
    ('first_name', 'first_name'),
    ('hometown', 'hometown'),
    ('email', 'email'),
]

FACEBOOK_EXTENDED_PERMISSIONS = ['email', ]

# Add email to requested authorizations.
LINKEDIN_SCOPE = ['r_basicprofile', 'r_emailaddress', 'r_fullprofile']
# Add the fields so they will be requested from linkedin.
LINKEDIN_EXTRA_FIELD_SELECTORS = ['email-address', 'headline', 'industry', 'public-profile-url',
                                  'interests', 'date-of-birth', 'positions', 'picture-url']
# Arrange to add the fields to UserSocialAuth.extra_data
LINKEDIN_EXTRA_DATA = [
            ('id', 'id'),
            ('first-name', 'first_name'),
            ('last-name', 'last_name'),
            ('email-address', 'email_address'),
            ('headline', 'headline'),
            ('industry', 'industry'),
            ('public-profile-url', 'public_url'),
            ('interests', 'interests'),
            ('date-of-birth', 'date_of_birth'),
            ('positions', 'positions'),
            ('picture-url', 'picture_url'),

            ]

SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'apps.account.pipeline.social_auth_user',  # to handle is_active = False as suspended user
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.associate.associate_by_email',
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.misc.save_status_to_session',
    'apps.account.pipeline.redirect_to_form',
    'apps.account.pipeline.set_username',
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.user.create_user',
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.social.associate_user',
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.social.load_extra_data',
    'apps.account.pipeline.update_email_validity',
    'apps.account.pipeline.set_user_details',
    'apps.account.pipeline.social_extra_data',
    'apps.account.pipeline.destroy_session_data',
)

SOCIAL_AUTH_PARTIAL_PIPELINE_KEY = 'partial_pipeline'

# for django-orm-extensions to not conflict with south
SOUTH_DATABASE_ADAPTERS = {'default': 'south.db.postgresql_psycopg2'}

# Amazon SES settings
# Email Configuration using Amazon SES Services
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django_ses.SESBackend'

# These are optional -- if they're set as environment variables they won't
# need to be set here as well
AWS_SES_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'XXX'
AWS_SES_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'XXX'

# Additionally, you can specify an optional region, like so:
AWS_SES_REGION_NAME = 'us-east-1'
AWS_SES_REGION_ENDPOINT = 'email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'


def get_cache():
    try:
        os.environ['MEMCACHE_SERVERS'] = os.environ['MEMCACHIER_SERVERS'].replace(',', ';')
        os.environ['MEMCACHE_USERNAME'] = os.environ['MEMCACHIER_USERNAME']
        os.environ['MEMCACHE_PASSWORD'] = os.environ['MEMCACHIER_PASSWORD']
        return {
          'default': {
            'BACKEND': 'django_pylibmc.memcached.PyLibMCCache',
            'TIMEOUT': 500,
            'BINARY': True,
            'OPTIONS': {'tcp_nodelay': True}
          }
        }
    except:
        return {
            'default': {
                'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.filebased.FileBasedCache',
                'LOCATION': '/tmp/django_kh_cache',
            }
        }

CACHES = get_cache()

# suit-django config
SUIT_CONFIG = {
    'ADMIN_NAME': 'Khooosh admin',
    # Set to empty string if you want to hide search from menu
    'CONFIRM_UNSAVED_CHANGES': False,
    'SEARCH_URL': '',
    'MENU_ICONS': {
        'sites': 'icon-leaf',
        'account': 'icon-user',
        'list': 'icon-th-list',
        'media': 'icon-file',
        'pages': 'icon-pencil',
    }
}

FILEBROWSER_SUIT_TEMPLATE = True

#locale path
# locale paths
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    base('locale'),
)

# mailchip API key
MAILCHIMP_API_KEY = 'XXXX'
MAILCHIMP_LIST_KEY = 'XXXXX'

# track hitcount app
RANK_HITCOUNT_TRACK = {
    'bargain-detail': {'app_label': 'bargain', 'model': 'Bargain', 'pk_view_variable': 'pk'},
    'promotion-detail': {'app_label': 'promotion', 'model': 'Promotion', 'pk_view_variable': 'pk'},
}

HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend.ElasticsearchSearchEngine',
        'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/',
        'INDEX_NAME': 'haystack',
    },
}

try:
    from local_env import *
except ImportError:
    pass

try:
    if os.environ['SETTING_FILE'] in ('staging', 'local_env', 'production'):
        exec('from khooosh.settings.%s import *' % os.environ['SETTING_FILE'])
except KeyError:
    pass


# tinymce setup - it should be after importing
# external settings, as this part uses STATIC_URL to determine location
TINYMCE_JS_URL = os.path.join(STATIC_URL, TEMPLATE_PUBLIC_ASSETS, 'vendors/tinymce/tinymce.min.js')

TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
    'plugins': "table,spellchecker,paste,searchreplace",
    'theme': "modern",
    'cleanup_on_startup': True,
    'custom_undo_redo_levels': 10,
}


CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "database"

STATIC_URL_THEME = '{0}{1}/'.format(STATIC_URL, TEMPLATE_PUBLIC_ASSETS)
```

Comment: Are you using a custom user model?

Comment: yes, but am configuring the custom model in the settings.py

Comment: The problem is that social_auth isn't able to figure out what your custom user model is. Post your `settings.py`

Comment: What is the parent model of your user class? Is it auth.User or auth.AbstractUser ?

Comment: Burhan, I just updated my question with settings.py file

Comment: Павел Тявин, am using both AbstractBaseUser and PermissionsMixin

Answer (score 0):

I had very similar error while logging into **Django 1.10.3** admin panel:
**AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'pk'.** I am using my own context processor (just like you) and it seems to cause the problem. Try to move your context processors **to the top** in **context_processor** list in settings.py. It helped in my case.